# problem with install Composer in php_info()

Tags: php, composer-php, installation

Hello I have problem with download Composer on windows, it's look nice at leas to I click on install!
it show me this message:

> **The Composer installer script did not run correctly. Script Output: PHP Warning:  phpinfo() has been disabled for security reasons in
>   C:\Users\R_H\AppData\Local\Temp\is-FM602.tmp\installer.php on line
>   371**

I click to retry so many times and it's useless!

Comment: Check the `disable_functions` line in your `php.ini` file. Ensure the `php_info` function isn't listed in there.

Comment: it's disable_functions=phpinfo

Comment: Remove the `phpinfo` bit, and it should work! :)

Comment: thanks it's work <3

Comment: No problem! I've added the comment above as an Answer so you can accept and close the Question :) thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `disable_functions` line in your `php.ini` file.

Ensure the `php_info` function isn't listed in there.

If it is, remove it:

---

**Before:**

`disable_functions=phpinfo`

**After:**

`disable_functions=`